# How to create a Bokeh DataTable DateTime formatter?

Tags: python, bokeh

Bokeh provides bokeh.models.DateFormatter() to show the date in a column (see [class DateFormatter(**kwargs)](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html#bokeh.models.widgets.tables.DateFormatter)). Is there a way to create a Formatter that also shows the time HH:MM:SS and possible also the milliseconds? When editing in the table(double click on a date) one can see the epoch milliseconds. I could create another column with another set of data having seconds of day and use [class NumberFormatter(**kwargs)](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html#bokeh.models.widgets.tables.NumberFormatter) with format "00:00:00" and another column with the milliseconds, but I would not be able to edit those and have it reflected on the graph glyphs, unless somehow I make the seconds of day data continuosly linked to the datetime values (is there a way to do so?). So I hope there is a way to work on a Formatter to display time out of the datetime data in a bokeh DataTable.

```
from datetime import datetime
import bokeh, bokeh.plotting

data = dict(dates=[datetime(2016, 12, 2,15,30,0,123456),
                   datetime(2016, 12, 2,15,30,5,250500),
                   datetime(2016, 12, 2,15,30,10,756050)],
            altitude=[100.,150.,125.])

source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(data)

columns = [bokeh.models.TableColumn(field="dates", title="Date",
           formatter=bokeh.models.DateFormatter()),
           bokeh.models.TableColumn(field="altitude", title="altitude")]

data_table = bokeh.models.DataTable(source=source, columns=columns,
                   row_headers=False,width=500, height=150, editable=True)

p = bokeh.plotting.figure(width=400,height=200,x_axis_type="datetime", 
                          background_fill_color="lightgray")
p.circle(x="dates",y="altitude",source=source, size=10)
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
bokeh.io.show(bokeh.io.gridplot([[p],[data_table]]))
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

A workaround is to create another column with the time HH:MM:SS (no milliseconds though. For that [@Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942168/how-to-create-a-bokeh-datatable-datetime-formatter/42418107#42418107) solution will work best). But editing that value will not be reflected in the graph. Editing the date milliseconds does update the graph but will not update the time column. Probably there is a way to connect the time column with the date column with some custom `CustomJS`. I have to comment that there is a working progress feature in bokeh github: [Updating dates in `datatable`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5402) that might help here a lot.

```
from datetime import datetime
import bokeh, bokeh.plotting

t1 = datetime(2016, 12, 2,15,30,0,123456)
t2 = datetime(2016, 12, 2,15,30,5,250500)
t3 = datetime(2016, 12, 2,15,30,10,756050)

data = dict(dates = [t1,t2,t3],
            times = [t1.hour*3600 + t1.minute*60 + t1.second,
                    t2.hour*3600 + t2.minute*60 + t2.second,
                    t3.hour*3600 + t3.minute*60 + t3.second],
            altitude=[100.,150.,125.])

source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(data)

tfmt = bokeh.models.NumberFormatter(format="00:00:00")
datefmt = bokeh.models.DateFormatter(format="ddMyy")
hfmt = bokeh.models.NumberFormatter(format="0.00")
columns = [bokeh.models.TableColumn(field="dates", title="Date",formatter=datefmt),
           bokeh.models.TableColumn(field="times", title="time", formatter=tfmt, editor=None),
           bokeh.models.TableColumn(field="altitude", title="altitude (km)", formatter=hfmt)]

data_table = bokeh.models.DataTable(source=source, columns=columns,
                   row_headers=False,width=500, height=150, editable=True)

p = bokeh.plotting.figure(width=400,height=200,x_axis_type="datetime", 
                          background_fill_color="lightgray")
p.circle(x="dates",y="altitude",source=source, size=10)
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
bokeh.io.show(bokeh.io.gridplot([[p],[data_table]]))
```

[image]

**UPDATE 04/13/2018**

Bokeh version 0.12.16dev allows for a `DataTable` to have a `DateFormatter` that supports time information:

```
bokeh.models.DateFormatter(format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

For all the possibilities see [class DateFormatter(**kwargs)](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html#bokeh.models.widgets.tables.DateFormatter).

[image]

Comment: Actually, there is no need for answer. The latests Bokeh already have that feature implemented.

Answer (score 1):

One partial solution is to separate the data sources for table and plot. Then you can leave the x-data for the plot in datetime format, and transform the date data for the table into a string. Of cause, then edits in the table are not reflected in the plot. Maybe with a callback function you can link the two data sources.

```
from datetime import datetime
import bokeh, bokeh.plotting

datetime_dates=[datetime(2016, 12, 2,15,30,0,123456),
                   datetime(2016, 12, 2,15,30,5,250500),
                   datetime(2016, 12, 2,15,30,10,756050)]
string_dates = []
for i in datetime_dates: string_dates.append(i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))

data_plt = dict(dates=datetime_dates,
                     altitude=[100.,150.,125.])
data_tbl = dict(dates=string_dates,
                     altitude=[100.,150.,125.])

source_plot  = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(data_plt)
source_table = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(data_tbl)

columns = [bokeh.models.TableColumn(field="dates", title="Date"),
           bokeh.models.TableColumn(field="altitude", title="altitude")]

data_table = bokeh.models.DataTable(source=source_table, columns=columns,
                   row_headers=False,width=500, height=150, editable=True)

p = bokeh.plotting.figure(width=400,height=200,x_axis_type="datetime", 
                          background_fill_color="lightgray")
p.circle(x="dates",y="altitude",source=source_plot, size=10)
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
bokeh.io.show(bokeh.io.gridplot([[p],[data_table]]))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y20z4.jpg)

Comment: That's a good suggestion. But if I keep a separate data for the `DataTable` then it's not interactive anymore, i.e. I won't be able to edit the column values and see the graph updated with those values, unless I create a callback function that once I modify the values, it updates the graph, which is the partial solution I created. I also see that there is a similar feature under development in bokeh github: Updating Dates in the datatable: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5402

Comment: Yes, if you need to update the plot from the table, you would have to use a callback function, or wait for the implementation of a datepicker in tables.